# why "Single-quoted string preferred over double-quoted string." in js?

Tags: javascript, gjslint

While using gjslint, I got a hint: "Single-quoted string preferred over double-quoted string".

So why? I'm a little confused with this. Why single-quoted preferred?

Hope to get some help. Thanks all.

Comment: well, for example, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) prefers the double quote strings over the single quote strings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's just somebody's opinion.

Lots of people do prefer singe-quotes, but lots of other people prefer double-quotes. I tend to use double-quotes just out of habit from other languages, but I don't have a strong preference: I'm willing to change if I hear of a compelling reason why single-quotes are better, but to date I've not even heard a *good* reason, let alone a *compelling* reason.

Even the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Strings) says that single-quotes are preferred without giving a good reason:

> "For consistency single-quotes (') are preferred to double-quotes (").
>   This is helpful when creating strings that include HTML"

(It then goes on to give a very short example of a string that doesn't even include HTML.)

A lot of people seem to believe XHTML is only valid with double-quotes, but that is not true: the XHTML spec allows either. (Having said that, 98% of the XML I've run across, including XHTML, *does* use double-quotes.)

Within any one source file I try to stick to one or the other, but if a line of code in the middle needed a lot of embedded quotes I'd be happy to change for just that line to avoid lots of escaping in that line.

**UPDATE:** Just remembered that JSON is only valid with double-quotes. Obviously JSON is not JavaScript, but still that's a reason why (a) some might prefer double-quotes in their JavaScript so that object literals look like JSON, and (b) some might prefer single-quotes so that they can manually encode JSON without having to escape the double-quotes. (No, I don't recommend manually encoding JSON, but I've seen it done.)

Comment: That's all fine until you run into some joker who's decided to parse XHTML with regexps…

Comment: @Donal - Ha! Well, such a person has more problems than which type of quotes I choose to use.

Comment: There is a famous SO answer for such people…

Comment: For those who haven't seen that answer: [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 16):

If you use single quotes, you do not have to escape the double quotes in your html.

For example...

With single quotes you can do this

`var a = '<a href="something.html" rel="yes" title="whatever">a link/a>';`

with double quotes you would need to escape those inside double quotes, like so

`var a = "<a href=\"something.html\" rel=\"yes\" title=\"whatever\">a link/a>";`

Much more work, more difficult to maintain, and easier to commit errors.

Comment: I can just use single quotes for HTML attributes.

Comment: True @BoltClock.  Although I think most people who dev in HTML use dbl quotes.

Comment: This also works the other way around, when you have Javascript strings inside attributes in the HTML (a common occurance with the templating engine I use)

Comment: I think the point is that sometimes you need to escape your double-quotes, and sometimes you're more concerned about escaping the apostrophes. Why not just switch to whichever is most contextually convenient? I can't find any evidence in my searching today, that the prejudice for single-quotes is justified, except perhaps as a convention for distinguishing between JSON and JS.

Answer (score 2):

My keyboard has a '/" key so I can easily type a single quote but need to press shift for the double quote. :)

As for the JSLint warnings its just trying to enforce an arbitrary standard in order to promote a more consistent coding style, just like how it does on other spacing and indentation issues.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, according with http://jsperf.com you get almost the same performance for both in some browsers, in others you get the same performance.

There's a lot of tests in jsperf and all of them get almost the same result:

- http://jsperf.com/double-or-simple-quote
- http://jsperf.com/quotes-compare
- http://jsperf.com/jquery-double-vs-single-quotes
- http://jsperf.com/search?q=quote

In conclusion I think using single or double quotes is just a matter of taste and not a matter of performance.

Regards.